# Выделение подмножеств из двумерного массива

Tags: php, алгоритм

Упрощенно:
Есть массив

```
[[0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0,1],
 [0,1,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Как записать замкнутые области, состоящие из единиц в отдельные массивы? Как вариант

```
[[0,1,1],
 [1,1,0],
 [0,1,0]]

[[1],
 [1]]
```

У меня только вариант пробежаться по всем строкам оригинального массива, записывая начала и конец последовательности единиц в отдельный список, а после прохода следующей строки сравнивать перекрытия. Но скорее всего это костылевелосипед, и существует приличное рациональное решение.
Как всегда, код можно не писать, но намекнуть как такое называется правильно по-буржуйски.

Comment: По идее, вам нужен flood fill. Если у PHP плохо с рекурсией, организуйте стек отложенных заданий вручную. (Разница между стеком и очередью соответствует поиску в глубину или ширину.)

Comment: Да, уже реализовал стеком. Не очередью, так как с очередью-через-массив у PHP тоже проблемы =/ С рекурсией проблем нет, есть проблемы с головой: я уже который раз пытаюсь использовать php для целей, для которых он не предназначен. :) Спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересная задача, не сталкивался пока. Вот похожая – сосчитать такие острова: [Islands in a two dimensional array](http://www.ritambhara.in/islands-in-a-two-dimensional-array/)

А ещё вспомнилось правило обхода лабиринта - правой рукой всегда касаться стены. Можно не считать 1, а «идти» по нулям, касаясь правой рукой 1. Когда маршрут замкнулся — обошли остров. После этого остров сохранить, островные 1 в исходном массиве обнулить. Правда, может подвести, если в острове дырка, а в ней ещё один изолированный суб-остров : )

Comment: Метод поджигателя мне понравился больше. Он не запутывается на кольце.

Comment: ...но в php утыкаюсь в ограничение рекурсии на больших островах. Проблема. =(

Comment: @knes, тогда ещё вариант: переводить массив в ч/б изображение и использовать графические библиотеки. Напр. [imagemagick умеет](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/separate/index.php) выделять области, залитые одним цветом. Т.е. на больших массивах php становится неэффективным, а вот с 1-битным изображением вполне можно работать. Задача выделения отдельных фигур постоянно встречается в распознавании текста (OCR).

И, может, вернуться к обходу лабиринта? Не знаю вашей задачи, но вдруг там дырки исключены?

Comment: А вообще можно вернуться и к построковому проходу один раз : )  Была недавно похожая задача: есть записи протяженных событий (начало, конец), нужно найти в любой момент времени, сколько их одновременно активно.

Можно идти по строке, и запоминать "изменения" состояний: были нули, стали единицы, или наоборот. И в следующей строке сопостовлять эти "события" с предыдущей.

Острова – простые-выпуклые, или могут быть "лабиринты"? Просто в одной прямоугольной области может поместиться и более одного острова, теоретически.

Comment: остров внутри острова исключен, точнее мы его будем рассматривать как один. А вот выпуклость - это проблема. Они, как правило, довольно левой формы. Мало того, нам надо еще учитывать их высоту, так что в BW перевести нельзя. Обход лабиринта тут плох еще и тем, что островов мало, а свободного места много. Imagic не люблю, так как он мало где есть. Кроме того, как я уже отметил, с "одним цветом" напряги: это все, вообще-то на очень неоднородном фоне. :)

Answer (score 2):

По ссылке, приведённой [@Sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks), используется рекурсивный алгоритм поиска в глубину. Если в PHP есть проблемы с глубиной рекурсии, можно сделать то же самое [поиском в ширину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83). Обычно этот алгоритм используют для поиска пути, но он также может использоваться для определения элементов, принадлежащих одной связанной области. Достаточно запустить поиск в любой точке острова, и в момент, когда очередь опустеет, алгоритм пометит как посещённые все клетки, принадлежащие острову.

Comment: в PHP *крайне* урезанная рекурсия - всего 100 вложений. Собственно, этого более чем хватает для тех задач, для которых он создавался.
Сейчас пытаюсь переписать под яву, но это уже иная история.