# Как найти диагонали прямоугольников в двумерном массиве

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Есть двумерный массив заполненный 1 и 0, где 1 это область прямоугольника.
В массиве может быть больше одного прямоугольника.
Как найти левый верхний и правый нижний углы всех прямоугольников?

Comment: Могут ли прямоугольники пересекаться?

Comment: немного не правильно сформулировал вопрос, просто 1 это разница двух массивов, а мне нужно обвести разницу прямоугольником

Comment: В общем, после сравнения 2х картинок на соответствие, получился двумерный массив, где его индексы это координаты, 1 разные пиксели а 0 одинаковые, мне нужно обвести области разных пикселей прямоугольником, все что пришло в голову это найти углы областей, но пока не могу понять как)

Comment: А пересекаться-то прямоугольники могут?

Comment: Если они пересекаются, то это должен быть один большой прямоугольник

Comment: [Перенесите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/757380/edit) уточнения из комментариев в текст вопроса. Какой прямоугольник вам нужен, минимальный повернутый на произвольный угол или параллельный сторонам изображений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для определения общего ограничивающего прямоугольника (*найти левый верхний и правый нижний углы* - т.е. всего два угла), достаточно простого перебора. Вот примерный код:

```
minx := width - 1;
miny := height - 1;
maxx := 0;
maxy := 0;

for i := 0 to height - 1 do
for k := 0 to width - 1 do
  if cell[i,k] = 1 then
  begin
    if k < minx then minx := k;
    if i < miny then miny := i;
    if k > maxx then maxx := k;
    if i > maxy then maxy := i;
  end;
```

Если нужно найти углы всех прямоугольников, то разбивайте массив на области (это тема для отдельного вопроса, например [Выделение подмножеств из двумерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/382332/)). Границы каждой области так же дадут вам необходимые углы.